# Wicket - loading data into table after page is rendered

Tags: java, ajax, wicket

In my wicket application I have a datatable. A dataprovider is attached to it and loads the content from a REST-Service. This call needs a lot of time (~ 20 seconds).

So, is there a way to load the page with an empty table and then refilling it after being rendered with data from the Service?

I thought about reattaching or reloading the dataprovider after the page is rendered:

```
onAfterRender()
```

But I still don't know how to do that with a dataprovider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a look at the `AjaxLazyLoadPanel` which shows a little loading icon as placeholder while the Component is loaded.

```
add(new AjaxLazyLoadPanel("table") {

    @Override
    public Component getLazyLoadComponent(String markupId) {
        return new MyLongLoadingTable(markupId);
    }
});
```

Another solution: show the empty table and periodically check for the database operation to complete and update the table when all data gathering has been done. The `AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior` is a good utility. Like this:

```
add(new AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior(Duration.ONE_SECOND) {

    @Override
    protected void onTimer(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

        if (isDataLoaded()) {
            stop(target);
            target.add(table);
        }

    }

});
```

Comment: Used the first one. Perfect. Thanks!